# Reportrlab - How to add a table at the beginning of each page

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am using ReportLab to generate a pdf.
I have a one-row table t. I need add it at the beginning of each page.
How I can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onFirstPage` and `onLaterPages` keyword arguments to the `DocTemplate.build` function for this.

They are called during layout before the pages are drawn. You can pass any function with the following signature:

```
def myOnFirstPage(canvas, document):
    ...

def myOnLaterPages(canvas, document):
    ...
```

Use them with

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('file.pdf')
doc.build(story, onFirstPage=myOnFirstPage, onLaterPages=myOnLaterPages)
```